# Как удалить bom из csv?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь в цикле выводить строки из csv-файла, но если в файле `bom` то файл некорректно обрабатывает строки.
Как удалить `bom`?

```
    if (($handle = fopen($this->filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $delimiter = $this->detectDelimiter($this->filename);
        $row = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if($row === 0 && $data[0] == 'first_name'){//здесь даже если значение 'first_name'
            // то проверка не срабатывает если в файле `bom`
                continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее регулярное выражение для вашей строки:

```
$bom = pack('H*', 'EFBBBF');
$str = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $bomStr);
```

Как вариант можно использовать аналогичную функцию:

```
function removeBomUtf8($s){
  if(substr($s,0,3)==chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))){
       return substr($s,3);
   }else{
       return $s;
   }
}
```

Comment: подскажите, `removeBomUtf8` нужно вызвать для всего файла csv целиком, поместив в функцию весь файл, или вызывать  для каждой строки отдельно? тогда это ведь затратно вроде для ресурсов

Comment: Метод работает со строкой, если получить содержимое `csv` файла, то оно будет записано в строку. Тогда вы сможете применить ее для этой перменной.

Comment: @word, BOM это маркер, с которым не умеет нормально работать PHP. Маркер этот располагается в начале файла/строки. Именно по-этому там `substr($s,0,3)` первые 4 символа.

Comment: маркер располагается в начале файла или в начале обрабатываемой строки в цикле? как удалить сразу из всего файла?

Comment: Сам маркер располагается в начале файла

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, `if (($handle = fopen($this->filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {` здесь считывается файл, значит нужно сначала конвертировать весь файл с помощью функции `removeBomUtf8` загрузив файл через `file_get_contents` ? а потом перед циклом сохранить с помощью `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: файл csv берётся из `$_FILES`

Comment: file_put_contents($_FILES['race_file']['tmp_name'],$csv);  так?

Comment: @word, `fgetcsv` читает строку из файла и производит разбор данных CSV, соответственно, вам надо один раз считать ее (первый раз), и убрать BOM, если таковой имеется.